# Math expression for indices of non-zero values from a matrix column

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors, matrix-equations

> Let the matrix $M = \begin{bmatrix}12&2&16&15\\6&8&18&0\\0&0&0&25\\3&20&0&2\end{bmatrix}$
>   and the matrix $J = \begin{bmatrix}22&2&6&5\\0&17&9&0\\10&0&0&5\\7&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$

I want to write the cosine similarity formula between a vector of non-zero values of the $k$ column of $M$ and the corresponding $k$ row of $J$ at the position of non-zero values of the $k$ column of $M$.

**If $k = 1$,**
 how to write the matrix symbols for $\begin{bmatrix}22&2&5\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}12&6&3\\\end{bmatrix}^T$ for using in cosine similarity formula as

$\frac{\begin{bmatrix}22&2&5\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}12&6&3\end{bmatrix}^T}{\lVert\begin{bmatrix}22&2&5\end{bmatrix}\rVert\lVert\begin{bmatrix}12&6&3\end{bmatrix}^T\rVert}$?

(Here are J 1st row at the position [1,2,4] with M 1st column at the position [1,2,4]. The position [1,2,4] comes from non-zero positions of M 1st column)

**If $k = 2$,**
it is $\begin{bmatrix}0&17&0\\\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2&8&20\end{bmatrix}^T$

(Here are J 2nd row at the position [1,2,4] and M 2nd column at the position [1,2,4]. Again, the position [1,2,4] comes from non-zero positions of M 2nd column)

**If $k = 3$,** it is $\begin{bmatrix}10&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}16&18\end{bmatrix}^T$

(J 3rd row at the position [1,2] is with M 3rd column at the position [1,2] because now only at the positions [1,2] of M 3rd column are non-zero)

Can I describe them as

> "calculate the cosine similarity between $J_{kg}$ and $M^T_{gt}$ where
>   $g$ was a vector of positions of non-zero values of $M$"?

Comment: Why exclude the positions where the column has zeros? The result is the same with or without them.

Comment: @DavidK because I want to exclude the positions of zero of $M$ and use the same set of positions for $J$. For example, if I use the first column of $M$, I want the positions $1,2,4$. Then I want to multiply it with the first row of $J$ at $1,2,4$ positions. Then 6 at the position $3$ of the first row of $J$ is excluded (whether it is zero or not).

Comment: Can you take another example with $k=2$, where the non-zero position of M column is zero at J row.

Comment: @Toby I added examples of $k=2$ and $k=3$ in the question.

Comment: Maybe something like this: "With two matrices $J$ and $M$ same size, $j$ is the column index and $i$ is the row index, where $M_{ij}\ne0$. Calculate the cosine similarity between two vector, one contain all $J_{ji}$ and another contain $M_{ij}$"

Comment: Your explanation is just a repetition of _what_ you want to do. You still have not explained _why._ Look: $[22\ 2\ 5][12\ 6\ 3]^T=[22\ 2\ 6\ 5][12\ 6\ 0\ 3]^T$, and $[0\ 17\ 0][2\ 8\ 20]^T=[0\ 17\ 9\ 0][2\ 8\ 0\ 20]^T$, and $[10\ 0][16\ 18]^T = [10\ 0\ 0\ 5][16\ 18\ 0\ 0]^T$. It seems to me you are putting yourself to extra trouble for nothing, and doing this to the reader of your work as well.

Comment: By the way, I write $[22\ 2\ 5][12\ 6\ 3]^T$ rather than $[22\ 2\ 5]\times[12\ 6\ 3]$ because $[22\ 2\ 5][12\ 6\ 3]^T$ is a standard matrix multiplication notation (a row times a column, resulting in the cosine similarity between the two) whereas the $\times$ symbol makes it look like you want a cross product, which is something completely different.

Comment: @DavidK Because calculating cosine similarity between $[22\ 2\ 5]$ and $[12\ 6\ 3]^T$ is not equal to calculating cosine similarity between $[22\ 2\ 6\ 5]$ and $[12\ 6\ 0\ 3]^T$. That's why I need the correct way to describe about extracting non-zero positions from matrix. Thanks for asking and correcting $\times$ symbol (I will correct the question). If it is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: Now you have been more explicit about the formulas you’re using, yes, I see where it makes a difference when you divide by the vector magnitude. So what you’re doing in effect is to project the $J$ row vector onto a subspace already occupied by the $M$ column vector.

Comment: @DavidK I am not sure whether the "occupied" in "a subspace already occupied by the $M$ column vector" has a similar meaning to "non-zero"? I am glad you understand my *why* and I would appreciate if you can give the answer below.